# How to redirect to a PUT or POST url with a button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, express

I have a button

```
<button class="delivery-orders-button" onclick="markDone(${order.order_id})">Dispatch order</button>
```

and I want **markDone** function to redirect the user to a put page like we do with forms and the order_id should be sent in the request body.
I do not wish to use the fetch api as redirecting like a form would be required because I wish to check for some browser cookies.

What is the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: *"I do not wish to use the fetch api as redirecting like a form would be required because I wish to check for some browser cookies."* Why would redirecting via a form prevent accessing cookies?

Comment: "What is the best way to achieve this result?" — Use a form.

Answer (score -1):

You can write like this in the function:

```
function markDone(order_id){
location.href = 'url_of_ur_page?order_id='+order_id;
}
```

Comment: That will trigger a GET request. The question was specific that it is looking for POST or PUT.